# Sheet Duplication Script : Protection not set when other user run the script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, permissions, protected

I am sharing a Google sheet with others with sharing enabled only with email ids. I have created a script that when run duplicates a master sheet and sets permission and protections as in the master sheet into the duplicated sheet. There is a button placed to execute this script in the master sheet.

When I (Owner) runs the script the protections get copied fine and other users are unable to access the protected cells but the problem arises when other editors of the sheet run the script the new sheet created gives them full access to edit all protected fields also.

The code i have written is as under:

```
function Protect() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var myValue = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  spreadsheet.duplicateActiveSheet();
  var totalSheets = countSheets() - 3;
  myValue = "DO" + totalSheets;
  SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().renameActiveSheet(myValue);
  var protection = spreadsheet.getActiveSheet().protect();
  protection.setUnprotectedRanges([spreadsheet.getRange('C2:E5'), spreadsheet.getRange('C6:D6'), spreadsheet.getRange('F5:G5'), spreadsheet.getRange('F6:G6'), spreadsheet.getRange('B9:B18'), spreadsheet.getRange('C9:G18'), spreadsheet.getRange('D20:D22'), spreadsheet.getRange('G20:G22'), spreadsheet.getRange('B20:B22'), spreadsheet.getRange('E21'), spreadsheet.getRange('E20')])
    .removeEditors(['user2@domain.com', 'user3@domain.com']);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G2').setValue(myValue);
  spreadsheet.getRange('G3').activate();
  spreadsheet.getRange('G3').setValue(new Date()).setNumberFormat('dd-MMM-YYYY');
  spreadsheet.getRange('C2').activate();
  hideImage();
};
```

Comment: Don't let other users run  the script?

Comment: The user running the script cannot be removed as an editor, so you should change your workflow in order to avoid them running the script. If you provide more information on your situation, maybe a workaround can be found.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually i have made a master sheet which on running the above function duplicates the sheet with the necessary protection for cells. 
The other users can duplicate the master sheet so that they can enter data as and when required hence rather then using the sheet duplicator function in google sheets i made the above code. Each user can duplicate the master sheet and enter data in the duplicated sheet.

Comment: That's kind of confusing, have you created the duplicator to avoid having your problem ? Or you are having this problem with the duplicator?